# Use multiple themes for splash activity depending on user's preference

Tags: android, styles, themes, splash-screen

How can I show different splash screens depending on the users preferences?

I've got several themes in my application, and when the user selects his prefered one, it is stored in `SharedPreferences`. In my activities I get the selected theme from prefs, call `setTheme(R.style.Any_Theme);` and then call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_any);` and it works perfect. But when I tried the same by calling the same `setTheme(R.style.Any_Theme);` in my splash activity, it didn't work as splash screen just uses `background` attribute in styles.

Splash background attribute

```
    <attr name="splashBackground" format="reference"/>
```

Base style for light themes

```
    <style name="BaseAppTheme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="splashBackground">@drawable/splash_light</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

Base style for dark themes

```
    <style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="splashBackground">@drawable/splash_dark</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

Splash themes that must be applied to the application depending on user preference

```
    <style name="SplashScreen.Light" parent="AppTheme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/splashBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashScreen.Blue" parent="AppTheme.Blue">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/splashBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashScreen.Dark" parent="AppTheme.Dark">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/splashBackground</item>
    </style>
    ...
```